# Objective-C NSImage, memory leak (any advice) I am using ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks

How can I fix this memory leak? Do I have a collection of NSBezierPath? How can I fix this memory leak? Any advice? I am using ARC.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        for(int j=0;j<5000;j++){
            NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
            NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(512, 512);
            NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:imageSize];
            //draw a line:
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
                [image lockFocus];
                float r1 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                float r2 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                float r3 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                float r4 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(r1, r2) toPoint:NSMakePoint(r3, r4)];
            }
            //...

            NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
            NSData *pngData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
            [image unlockFocus];

            NSString *jstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j];
            jstring = [jstring stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
            [pngData writeToFile:jstring atomically:YES];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, i am little new. I like just to make 5000 pictures with random lines on it.

Answer (score 5):

Revised answer, now that I know you're using ARC:

It's probably not that you're leaking, but that your autorelease pool is becoming bigger and bigger with every iteration of your loop, because the autorelease pool isn't going to empty until your loop has finished.

What you need to do is to employ secondary autorelease pools inside your loop. Here's a revised version of your code to illustrate this.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        for(int j=0; j<5000; j++) {
            NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
            NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(512, 512);
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:imageSize];
                //draw a line:
                NSData *pngData;
                for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
                    [image lockFocus];
                    float r1 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                    float r2 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                    float r3 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                    float r4 = (float)(arc4random() % 500);
                    [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(r1, r2) toPoint:NSMakePoint(r3, r4)];
                    //...

                    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
                    pngData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
                    [image unlockFocus];
                }

                NSString *jstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j];
                jstring = [jstring stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
                [pngData writeToFile:jstring atomically:YES];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You do seem to have one other problem, though. Are you constructing a full path for your files?

Comment: @user1735714 See my edit. `pngData` needed to be declared outside the scope of your loop.

Comment: @user1735714 you really need to be specific about what steps you've changed that's prompted these errors, exactly what the error messages say, which line the compiler is complaining about (for compiler errors), etc. People can't help when all they have is vague, incomplete information about the problems you're seeing.

Comment: @user1735714 One more edit. Moved your `[image lockFocus];` line inside the loop.

Comment: As the code gets longer and longer and sections become more defined, why not use methods? The fact that the OP didn't doesn't mean that you shouldn't. @user1735714 did this fix the problem?

Comment: @user1735714 Take one last look at my edited answer; I was able to run it myself.